# Not able to send firebase pushnotification in IOS using java

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending firebase push notification using Java for IOS. below are my code.

```
    public class SendNotifi {
    public final static String AUTH_KEY_FCM = "AIzaSyBgF...............";
    public final static String API_URL_FCM = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    // userDeviceIdKey is the device id you will query from your database     
    public static void pushFCMNotification(String userDeviceIdKey) throws     Exception{

    String authKey = AUTH_KEY_FCM;   // You FCM AUTH key
    String FMCurl = API_URL_FCM;     

    URL url = new URL(FMCurl);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization","key="+authKey);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("to",userDeviceIdKey.trim());
    JSONObject info = new JSONObject();

    info.put("title", "Notificatoin Title - IOS");   // Notification title
    info.put("body", "Hello Test notification - IOS"); // Notification body
    info.put("badge", "1"); 
    json.put("notification", info);
    json.put("priority", "high");

    System.out.println("json : " +json);

    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(json.toString());
    wr.flush();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    System.out.println(response.toString());
    }
    public static void main(String main[])
    {
        try {
            SendNotifi.pushFCMNotification("e_0k8MPAXpI:APA91bFrz3MkWS0V9E_PJMGwtFppYhR6ap9rD53nB-Wxkosij1jDDuPDXRw__l4tzOOsGaEm_j02a20oJGLimKvTuZSqRs6aTcbizTMuYMp6_1jB4U7RCl2A_NdWEHIMlaAl6YN1o_Hv");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It is not work fine for IOS.

I got confirmation success in response, but I did not get any push noitfication in IOS.

```
{"multicast_id":6591278961512996707,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1474009869605736%2f4186c42f4186c4"}]}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39506040/how-to-send-push-notifications-to-iphone-using-fcmfirebase-console-in-php/39507857#comment66329255_39506040

Comment: Do you receive the notification properly when you send the notification via the Firebase Console?

Comment: Yes Dear, I had sent via Firebase Console and it's work fine.

Comment: Have you tried what @Shubhank linked? By adding the `priority` parameter and setting it to `high` in your payload?

Comment: Yes, I have also added priority field in payload. but still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

To start off, I'm going to mention that there are two types of message payloads for FCM. notification and data. See the documentation here

When sending notifications through the Firebase Notifications Console, it will be treated as a notification payload. However, if you add in Custom Data, it will add it in the payload as a custom key-value pair.

For example, in your post, the FCM payload should look something like this:

```
{
    "notification": {
    "body": "Some one invited you.",
    "title": "Friend request notification",
    "mutable-content": true,
    "icon": "myicon",
    "sound": "tri-tone"
},
"data": {
    "category": "provider-body-panel",
    "mutable-content": true,
    "click_action": "provider-body-panel"
    }
}
   "registration_ids": ["<REGISTRATION_TOKEN_HERE>"],
   "priority": "high"
}
```

What's wrong?
mutable-content should be mutable_content (notice the underscore) and should be on the same level as notification.
(this one I might've misunderstood, but) There is no category parameter for FCM, click_action already corresponds to it.
See the docs for the parameters here.

It it is currently not possible to set the value for click_action and mutable_content when using the Firebase Notifications Console. You'll have to build the payload yourself, something like this:

```
 {
        "to": "<REGISTRATION_TOKEN_HERE>",
        "mutable_content" : true,
        "notification": {
            "body" : "Some one invited you.",
            "title": "Friend request notification",
            "click_action" : "provider-body-panel"
        }
    }
```

Then send it from your own App Server. You could also do this by using Postman or cURL.

This is working for me, wish too you too.