# Firebase PHP don't work for IOS

Tags: php, android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a small problem

I use FireBase for push notification on iOS and Android.

On Android it work, on iOS it work only when i send message by the console when i send message with PHP it's not good

My php code

```
function sendGCM($message, $id) {


$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

$fields = array (
        'registration_ids' => array (
                $id
        ),
        'data' => array (
                "message" => $message
        )
);
$fields = json_encode ( $fields );

$headers = array (
        'Authorization: key=' . "*****",
        'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );

$result = curl_exec ( $ch );

curl_close ( $ch );
}
```

Do you know why ?

Thanks :)

Comment: You just posted your Firebase auth key to the Internet. You should consider your account compromised and disable this key immediately.

Comment: I forget, i disable the key now, thanks

Comment: You'll probably want to set high priority to ensure iOS shows the messages. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39506040/how-to-send-push-notifications-to-iphone-using-fcmfirebase-console-in-php/39507857#39507857